# why rdiff backup needs to be installed on server end as well?

Tags: backup

I am newbie in working with rdiff. 
I am taking the backup using rdiff from client to server end.
can anyone tell me why we need to install rdiff backup at server end as well?
hwo it works?
rdiff access file systems of connect to the rdiff on server?

Answer (score 1):

The suggested solution with mountable file systems are barely usable though. And that is exactly why you need rdiff on the server, as it makes delta calculations and optimizes the throughput by sending only information needed as a result. Otherwise why even bother using rdiff at all ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need rdiff on the remote side... if you have SFTP-access. Have a look at [this article](http://wiki.rdiff-backup.org/wiki/index.php/BackupToSshfsMountTake) on the rdiff wiki page.

In general you don't need rdiff on the remote side if you can access the remote filesystem in some other way like NFS or CIFS (although CIFS has been troublesome for some users).

Comment: Technically correct, but not practical. As mentioned by SPDenver, the main point of using an rsync-based solution (like rdiff) is to minimize the amount of traffic passing over a network link (which is much slower than local disk access).

What you suggest results in the entire remote file being copied to the local system (via SFTP/NFS/CIFS) so it can be compared to the local file and the differences isolated.

Rsync in contrast generates (much) smaller checksums and transmits them between client and server, and once they've been used to find differences then sends the differences only.

Comment: The author's own description of how the algorithm works is at https://rsync.samba.org/tech_report/ - quite an interesting read (if that's your sort of thing).